# Saving dynamically loaded inputs as a array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to load multiple sub-categories after selecting a specific category, but if I use **[i]** in the ngModel of sub-categories fields then the data is not loaded and if I remove the **[i]** then it loads correctly but if I type in on ion-input then it loads in all ion-inputs and also the data is not saved correctly as it is not working as an array.

This is the selection for loading data.

```
<ion-select
  [(ngModel)]="selected_option"
  (ionChange)="optionChanged()"
  interface="popover"
>
  <ion-select-option
    value="{{category.id}}"
    *ngFor="let category of categories;"
    (ionChange)="clickOption()"
    >{{cateogry.name}}</ion-select-option
  >
</ion-select>
```

After the selected option multiple sub-categories will be loaded as below:

```
     <details
        *ngFor="let sub of sub-categories; let i = index;"
      >
        <summary>{{sub.name}}</summary>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-input type="date" [(ngModel)]="datefrom[i]"></ion- 
           input>
            <ion-input type="date" [(ngModel)]="dateto[i]"> 
            </ion-input>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="amount[i]"></ion-input>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-input type="text" value="{{sub.id}}" [(ngModel)]="id[i]"></ion-input>
      </details> 
      ...
```

But when I load the sub-categories then this error occurs and data are not shown:

*ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')*

I want that the dynamically loaded sub-categories must work as in array because I want to save it as array.

Answer (score 0):

ok, do it like this

```
<details
        *ngFor="let sub of sub-categories; let i = index;"
        
      >
```

sub is already an instance of sub-categories as sub = sub-categories[i] (like i in for loop), so sub[0] or sub[1] is giving you undefined here.
Remove this i and check if problem persists.

ngModel is a 2 way binding property. You can not bind directly sub here to ngModel as it will not detect any changes this way.

You can do something like this here

```
<ion-input type="date" [(ngModel)]="datefrom[i]" value="sub.datefrom"></ion- 
           input>
```

Refer to this link for more:
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-two-way-data-binding-ngmodel-example

Comment: When I do that I get this error in console. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "sub". Template variables are read-only.

Comment: I already tried to remove [i = index] from foreach loop but the problem is that the dynamic input names will become the same and inputs will take duplicated values. And also if I remove the {} bracket from the ion-input value it will be displayed as string.

Comment: when I use [i = index] it will display one value the reset is empty.     
https://ibb.co/wNQS6td

Comment: I had already removed that i for you, I meant that i here  [(ngModel)]="sub[i]" .

Comment: you can keep your rest of the code as it was just add value="sub.correspondingValue" in every input field

Comment: I removed the [(ngModel)]="sub[i]" completely from code it was not needed for my codes. the problem still exists.

Comment: what is happening now.. please update your post with latest edits and errors

Comment: when I added value="sub.correspondingValue" in every input value, In bowser it displays like sub.correspondingValue inside input.

Comment: ok sorry to say, but you need to work on your basics. value = "{sub.correspondingValue}" meant whatever value you want to pass to that input as you are using 2 way binding here. Please check the syntax as per the language you are using.

Comment: I got ur point I used the actual or corresponding values instead.

Comment: Yes, may lead you to your solution.

Comment: The problem is not solved. Please remember that datefrom and dateto and amount will be filled after the sub-categories are loaded and only id is pre-defined.